# Passing username to the url Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

So I decided to change the look of the urls in my application. The current look is something like that: `/user/profile`. This is the page the user sees, after he's logged in.

I want to pass the `$username` to the url, something like this: `/name_of_the_user/profile`

This is what I tried so far:

Route:

```
Route::get('/{user}/profile', [
'uses' =>'UserController@getProfile',
'as' => 'user.profile',
'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

Link:

```
<a href="{{ route('user.profile',auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->username : 'default') }}">User Profile</a>
```

This is partially working.

When the user logs in, he gets this error:

> UrlGenerationException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17:
>   Missing required parameters for [Route: user.profile] [URI: {user}/profile].

But if I reload the page its ok. The username passed successfully to the url as it supposed to.

How can I fix this error?

I should say that a user goes to `/user/signin` to sign in and he is being redirected to `/user/profile`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some default value for users who are not logged in:

```
auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->username : 'default'
```

If you want to redirect not logged in users, use [`auth` middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication) or custom [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware) for that.

Comment: He **is** using the auth middleware and this is occurring when he logs in and redirects to the logged in users profile.

Comment: @AndreasElia he doesn't use it for method which builds URL.

Comment: Well this just added a 'default' to the sign in page:  `/user/signin?default`.
But the error still appears.

Comment: @daino92 it should create normal URL. Show the full code you use please (full `a href`).

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin do you mean in the header? I will edit the post if it is.

Comment: @daino92 your original question has code for `{user}/profile` link only, but you've added code from my answer to different links. You should add it to profile link only.

Comment: Since you have added `Auth::check()` you should always get username now and you don't need to add code form my answer. Just make sure all users have `username` and original code will work just fine with `Auth::check()`

Comment: I was experimenting with the other links. I tried adding `auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->username : 'default'` to the profile link only but still the error appears.

Comment: You're using two commas. Remove one. Also, put {{ dd(auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->username : 'default') }} before the profile link and tell me what does it return please.

Comment: It gives me the same error. If I try to reload, it will show the site like the user is logged in, but the site will be partially broken; I can only see the header. Not the content or the footer.

Comment: That's how `dd()` works, it's normal. It should show you `null` or some kind of dump at the end. So, what does it show?

Comment: After the error, it only show the header. The rest is blank. Like this: https://postimg.org/image/p6653izax/

Answer (score 0):

### Header

```
<a href="{{ route('user.profile', Auth::user()->username) }}">User Profile</a>
```

If not working :

```
<a href="{{ route('user.profile', Auth::user()->username ? : 'nousernamefound') }}">User Profile</a>
```

Comment: Its practically the same answer as AlexeyMezenin gave me, so I still get that error.